# How detect why lock table row?

Tags: php, postgresql, locking

I working with PHP 7 (5.6.11) and postgresql 9.4 on Ubuntu 15.10 and Freebsd.

My code select single row by id from table with "for update" option.
Sometimes (one case of hundreds) this query executes very long time, about 20-90 seconds. My code working in about 30 threads.

As I understand, "select * from table for update" lock only single row in table and i can get such behavior only if another process already select this row. Is i right? But it can't happend because script executing only after getting message from message broker.

Single message for single row. So i can't imagine who and why can block this row. (`select * from table for update` used in one place, where I get message from queue).

I try use info from pg_locks and ps ax output. I save this info before select for update and then, if i catch long query, i send this info in logs. I see pid of process that locking table, but i don't see this pid in ps ax output. This confuses me.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You're going to need to provide documentation for this. Assuming this is the only query that "pauses" at this moment then it does sound like locking. However, I've never heard of a lock not being listed in pg_locks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found reason. I use own task manager that work with ActiveMQ. Sometimes for some reasons task manager set pause for some kind of tasks. Then, after some event, task unpaused and resend in queue. Resending wrapped in database and ActiveMQ transactions.

For work with ActiveMQ i use this library: https://github.com/centraldesktop/php-stomp

For sending messages i use sync mode and i found, that i forgot use this mode for transactions. So when task resends in queue, first messages got into the queue without transactions, they run scripts and... And this scripts should wait until resender finish resend tasks and commit his database transactions.

Answer (score -1):

Different database products use drastically different locking mechanisms.  Some, when you do a `select * from table for update where id=34` may lock one row, or one block.  You need to read the official documentation.

If you do a `select * from table for update` without any criteria, you will lock the entire table until you `commit` or `rollback`

Comment: I check this, my request by id in postgresql lock only single row.